# Google Analytics: Capture Zipcode on Form Submit

Tags: google-analytics

We have a dealer locator that we would like to see what zip codes people are entering into the field before hitting submit. Is it possible to capture that as an event when they hit the submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although technically this is possible to do, you would need to check with your legal team, or do your due diligence, and make sure that this is not in violation of Google Analytics terms of usage. My senses tell me it is, but you would need to check yourself.

[Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/is-it-possible-to-get-the-zip-codes-of-visitors-with-google-analytics) is a similar post.

And here are the [GA Terms of Service.](https://www.google.ca/analytics/terms/us.html)